# @Query Annotation in Spring Cassandra Repository not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use @Query Param for Cassandra repository in Java Springboot.

But its not working. Below is the sample code.

```
@Repository
public interface Table1Repository extends CassandraRepository<Table1,TransactionKey>{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE code=?0 and product=?1 and id=?2 order by transactiontime DESC limit ?3")
    List<Table1> searchTransactionLimit(String code,String product,Double id, int limit);
    
}
```

If I hardcode the value of id within the @Query, then its working.
For example,

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE code=?0 and product=?1 and id=17.0 order by transactiontime DESC limit ?3")
```

SO basically, type String and int are working in @Query. But type Double is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below also but that limit number need to there in method name.

```
List<Table1> findTop10ByCodeAndProductAndIdOrderByTransactiontimeDesc(String code,String product,Double id);
```

you can try the below also by pageable.

```
Pageable pages = PageRequest.of(0, limit);

findByCodeAndProductAndIdOrderByTransactiontimeDesc(String code,String product,Double id,Pageable pages  );
```